# Canvas animation and animationFrame, snake effect

Tags: javascript, canvas, requestanimationframe, cancelanimationframe

I am drawing four rectangles in my canvas, one for each side that goes back and forth (or up and down) automatically. What I would like to create is a snake effect, where for example my animation starts with the rectangle on the top that goes all the way forth till the end of `canvas.width` and then my rectangle on the right side will start animating from top to bottom and so on with the other rectangles. What can I do to achieve this kind of animation?

Check out my code: https://jsfiddle.net/4kdrLde8/

```
function drawRecTop(recTop, context) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(recTop.x, recTop.y, recTop.width, recTop.height);
    context.fillStyle = '#FB0202';
    context.fill();
}

function drawRecRight(recRight, context) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(recRight.x , recRight.y , recRight.width, recRight.height);
    context.fillStyle = '#FB0202';
    context.fill();
}

function drawRecBottom(recBottom, context) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(recBottom.x , recBottom.y , recBottom.width, recBottom.height);
    context.fillStyle = '#FB0202';
    context.fill();
}

function drawRecLeft(recLeft, context) {
     context.beginPath();
     context.rect(recLeft.x , recLeft.y , recLeft.width, recLeft.height);
     context.fillStyle = '#FB0202';
     context.fill();
}

function animate(myRectangle, canvas, context, startTime) {
    // update
    recTop.x ++;
    recRight.y ++;
    recBottom.x -- ;
    recLeft.y --;

    // clear
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    drawRecTop(recTop, context);
    drawRecRight(recRight, context);
    drawRecBottom(recBottom, context);
    drawRecLeft(recLeft, context);


    // request new frame
    requestAnimFrame(function() {
        animate(myRectangle, canvas, context, startTime);
    });
}


var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var recTop = {
    x: -180,
    y: 0,
    width: 150,
    height: 20
};

var recRight = {
    x: 480,
    y: 0,
    width: 20,
    height: 150
};

var recBottom = {
    x: 480,
    y: 480,
    width: 150,
    height: 20
};

var recLeft = {
    x: 0,
    y: 480,
    width: 20,
    height: 150
};

// wait one second before starting animation
setTimeout(function() {
    var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    animate(recTop, canvas, context, startTime);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Hey intro_coder, I think you need to give us some more information. Unfortunately I don't understand what you mean with *"I want them to animate when the previous animation ends, creating a snake effect."*. Could you clarify that for us please?

Comment: Hey..I've just update my post..I hope I clarified myself.

Comment: You are drawing and updating all your rectangles at the same time. You need to only update one at a time, and use `if()` to check which one should update.